# How to read temp from DS18B20 using UART board

Tags: c++, c, uart

I bought board like this [image: board] now i want to connect temperature sensor to this board.
How to read temperature from sensor in c or c++?
I tried to write some code but it won't work. I connect DS18B20 data cabel directly to TXD and RXD pins.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <errno.h>

int
set_interface_attribs (int fd, int speed, int parity)
{
    struct termios tty;
    memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
    if (tcgetattr (fd, &tty) != 0)
    {
            std::cout<<"error "<<errno<<" from tcgetattr";
            return -1;
    }

    cfsetospeed (&tty, speed);
    cfsetispeed (&tty, speed);

    tty.c_cflag = (tty.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8;     // 8-bit chars
    // disable IGNBRK for mismatched speed tests; otherwise receive break
    // as \000 chars
    tty.c_iflag &= ~IGNBRK;         // ignore break signal
    tty.c_lflag = 0;                // no signaling chars, no echo,
                                    // no canonical processing
    tty.c_oflag = 0;                // no remapping, no delays
    tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;            // read doesn't block
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;            // 0.5 seconds read timeout

    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // shut off xon/xoff ctrl

    tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);// ignore modem controls,
                                    // enable reading
    tty.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);      // shut off parity
    tty.c_cflag |= parity;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

    if (tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
    {
        std::cout<<"error "<<errno<<" from tcsetattr";
            return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void
set_blocking (int fd, int should_block)
{
    struct termios tty;
    memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
    if (tcgetattr (fd, &tty) != 0)
    {
        std::cout<<"error "<<errno<<" from tggetattr";
            return;
    }
    tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = should_block ? 1 : 0;
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;            // 0.5 seconds read timeout

    if (tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
            std::cout<<"error "<<errno<<" setting term attributes";
}

int main()
{
        char *portname = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
        int tty_fd = open (portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
        if (tty_fd < 0)
        {
            std::cout<<"error "<<errno<<" opening "<<portname<<": "<< strerror (errno);
                return -1;
        }

        set_interface_attribs (tty_fd, B9600, 0);  // set speed to 115,200 bps, 8n1 (no parity)
        set_blocking (tty_fd, true);

        unsigned char c = 0xCC;
        if(!write(tty_fd, &c, sizeof(c)))
            std::cout<<"Write error";

        sleep(2);

        unsigned char buffer[8];
        int size;
        if((size = read(tty_fd, &buffer, 8)) < 0)
                std::cout<<"Error";
        else
            std::cout<<"CC("<<size<<")='"<<buffer<<"'";

        std::cout<<"\n";

        c = 0x44;
        if(!write(tty_fd, &c, sizeof(c)))
            std::cout<<"Write error2";

        c = 0xBE;
        if(!write(tty_fd, &c, sizeof(c)))
            std::cout<<"Write error2";

        sleep(2);

        if((size = read(tty_fd, &buffer, 8)) < 0)
                std::cout<<"Error";
        else
            std::cout<<"BE("<<size<<")='"<<buffer<<"'";

        std::cout<<"\n######################\n";

        close(tty_fd);
}
```

I got:

```
CC(1)='Č@'
BE(2)='@ž@'
######################
CC(1)='Č@'
BE(2)='@ž@'
######################
CC(1)='Č@'
BE(2)='@ž@'
######################
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Two possible problems: Are you sure you get the data *as text*? And if you do, are you sure the data is zero-terminated?

Comment: Are you sure you use the right device file. If I plug in an Arduino  UNO. I should connect to `/dev/ttyACM0`.

Comment: I connect UART to laptop. When i run application the TXD and RXD LED are blinking.

Comment: Do you also have code that demonstrates how you write from your device?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with **any** software. The DS18B20 is electrically incompatible with the board you have. The sensor uses a 1-wire, open-collector communication scheme that is completely different from the serial protocol normally used with this board. With great difficulty you might be able to do some bit-banging of the RTS/CTS signals but you need circuitry to combine them into a bidirectional open-collector signal.

Comment: Seems unlikely.  It is the chip itself that uses the Maxim 1-wire protocol.  The board certainly seems to break it out into standard serial port signals.  A 1-wire protocol doesn't have room for RTS and CTS :)  And he's actually getting data back.

Comment: So using this board to read data from DS18B20 will be extremaly hard? How to read temperature from sensor on laptop?

Comment: @HansPassant Without a datasheet of the board, from the looks and the labelling ``FT232`` it really more looks like a FTDI usb-to-serial board, which does not speak 1-wire.

Comment: so how to connect this sensor to laptop?

Comment: @skoczo [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Wire#External_links) has some suggestions. Otherwise you could use an Arduino to interface with the DS18B20.

Comment: @HansPassant The fact that the board responds to some sort of electrical activity on the connections does not mean that "he's actually getting data". The Maxim 1-wire protocol is completely different from the normal UART serial protocol. It simply cannot work with "standard serial port signals".

Comment: Sure it can, just don't receive and transmit at the same time.  And include a pull-up resistor, no doubt present on the board.  Which automatically begets a master-slave protocol, it only sends something back after you send it a command.

Comment: @HansPassant No, sorry, check Figure 10 in the data sheet. Every device connected to the 1-wire bus must have an open-drain or three-state transmit output. That's not how normal serial interfaces work. Furthermore, data 1 and 0 are not defined by voltage levels but by the pulse high time within a data slot period.

Answer (score 1):

You can hack the UART to communicate with 1 wire protocol.
Connect Rx to Tx and add 4.7 pull-up resistor
See the application note from maxim:

http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/214

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by user3804701, it's indeed possible to communicate with a 1-Wire device using a UART interface, and the application note at https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/214 contains all the information needed to make it work.
But the OP's code needs several fixes:

- Each transaction with DS18B20 is made of 3 steps: initialization (also called reset), ROM command and function command, optionally followed by a data exchange
- The initialization or reset step is performed by configuring the UART with 9600 bps baud rate, transmitting 0xF0, and receiving a dummy byte; then, the baud rate must be set to 115200 bps to perform the next steps
- Following the reset step, data is sent to DS18B20 by writing to the UART a 0xFF byte for each data bit set to 1, and a 0x00 byte for each bit set to 0, starting from the least significant bit; for example, to send 0xAB (i.e. 10101011), one would write to the UART the sequence (FF FF 00 FF 00 FF 00 FF); for each byte written to the UART, there is a "return byte" that needs to be read from the UART and discarded
- Data is received from DS18B20 by sending the 0xFF byte following the rules in the previous bullet point, but instead of discarding the "return bytes" reading from the UART a byte for each data bit, starting from the least significant bit: a 0xFF value means that the bit value is 1, otherwise the bit value is 0; for example, the sequence (00 FF FF 00 FF 00 00 FF) read from the UART means that DS18B20 sent 0x96 (i.e. 10010110)
- If there is just one DS18B20 connected to the 1-Wire bus, all transactions can use "skip ROM" (byte value 0xCC) as ROM command
- The first transaction to be performed is the one that triggers a temperature conversion from DS18B20, with function command 0x44
- After waiting for the conversion to complete (which can take up to 750 ms), the host can perform a second transaction to read the DS18B20 scratchpad memory (function command 0xBE); the scratchpad memory is 9 bytes long and contains among other things the temperature value

So in summary the steps needed to get a temperature sample from DS18B20 are: reset, write 0xCC, write 0x44, wait for conversion, reset, write 0xCC, write 0xBE, read 9 bytes.

Example code that implements this stuff is available at https://github.com/dword1511/onewire-over-uart.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Maybe a minor detail, the reset pulse is sent with a `0xF0` I think, not a `0x0F`. But thanks a bunch for the detailed answer. After reading through the DS18b20 datasheet a couple of times, and re-reading your answer, I was able to read the temp on an imx rt 1024

Comment: You are right, the reset pulse is sent with the 0xF0 value. I edited my answer to fix that. Thanks